# setup environment in u-boot SPL

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

Is there any option to load the environment variables in u-boot SPL?
I have a device (Arria10 SoC) in which a part of the FPGA firmware is loaded in u-boot SPL by using the Firmware Loader API.
This allows the usage of the environment variables *storage_interface* and *fw_dev_part* to define the storage.

I was able to set the variables in u-boot and store them to the MMC device. u-boot also reads the variables correct. But in SPL the environment variables aren't initialized.

Is it possible to load it in SPL and use the values from MMC?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment is initialized by calling env_init(). Other boards call this function in the board or architecture specific spl.c file in either of the following functions:

- board_boot_order()
- board_init_f()
- board_init_r()
- spl_start_uboot()

Just grep for 'env_init(' to find the code locations.

You will have to implement one of the functions.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I was able to call the ´env_init()´ function in the ´spl_board_init()´ function specifically for our board. I had also to call ´mmc_initialize(gd->bd);´ for MMC initialization and ´env_load()´ for loading the environment from mmc.

Comment: If you think that this is useful for all users of arria10 boards, would you mind to send a patch upstream?

Comment: Yes, maybe it could be useful for other arria10 users. I think by default it should be without MMC and environment initialization in SPL u-boot but an additionally configuration option could handle that. Right now, I'm working on the following fork: https://github.com/altera-opensource/u-boot-socfpga and it seams that the changes are not pushed back to https://source.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot since a long time. Unfortunately, I'm not sure who is the maintainer of the socfpga repository to which I could send the patch. Do you have any idea or proposal?

Comment: I don't know who is behind rocketboards.org. Upstream U-Boot comes with scripts/get_maintainer.pl which determines who should receive an email with the patch. Please, use 'git send-email' for sending to avoid problems with formatting by email clients.